# Ant cannot create task name is undefined

Tags: ant

I'm using Ant with eclipse and everything was working fine, until I decided to do some house keeping and created 2 sub directories under my Ant dir.

I moved my `build.xml` to the sub directory and now nothing is working an I get:

> BUILD FAILED C:\Users\OdedHarniv\Workspaces\Force.com
>   IDE\vidmind\ANTs\Vid Service\build.xml:26: Problem: failed to create
>   task or type antlib:com.salesforce:retrieve Cause: The name is
>   undefined.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like `antlib:com.salesforce:retrieve` is defined in a file named `ant-salesforce.jar`. Where is this file on your computer?

Comment: I didn't find such a jar, which is strange since before the dir change everything was working. I added it and it is now working

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible problems

**1** You have a relative path defined somewhere in your ant file, or a file that you are importing. Note that if you are importing e.g. a properties file, relative paths in that one will be interpreted relative to the directory containing the main ant file.

**2** If you are running through Eclipse, it will run through a run-configuration. That might have extra jars put on its class path. I expect Eclipse will create a new run configurations when you move the file, which has the default class path. Too see your run configuration go to `Run > External Tools > External Tools....`